# iOS controlled delay in live streaming

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, avfoundation, audio-streaming

Which is the best way in order to buffer and play a live streaming from http in swift?
I know that AVPlayer already buffers the streaming, but I need to control the delay and make it variable and settable from external.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question? I want to do the same thing

Comment: not yet, but however I've given up.

Comment: I attended an iOSmeetup and met a dev who works at Instagram. He said his entire job focused on video and nothing else. He said his job was beyond AVFoundation and his team's main focus was VideoToolBox which is a very low level video framework. He knew his stuff. He said Instagram and every mobile live video feed that exists has a 5 sec delay and that's just the way it is. He didn't get more detailed then that. Maybe this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50598525/4833705 or perhaps this: https://www.slideshare.net/instinctools_EE_Labs/videostream-compression-in-ios