# AVPlayer stops playing video after buffering

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avkit

When I load a video from the internet (10-40MB large) I am unable to provide a smooth playing experience.

My AVPlayer either loads the whole video and then plays it, or plays 1s, buffers and then just stops playing.

I tried endless libraries, buffer-observer methods, and tutorials. Nothing seems to help.

```
    .
    .
    .

    self.makeLoaderVisible()

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .new, context: nil)
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .new, context: nil)
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: .new, context: nil)

    avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    avPlayer?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    avPlayer?.playImmediately(atRate: 0)
//  avPlayer?.play()

    }


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if object is AVPlayerItem {
        switch keyPath! {
        case "playbackBufferEmpty":
            // Show loader
            makeLoaderVisible()

        case "playbackLikelyToKeepUp":
            // Hide loader
            hideLoader()

        case "playbackBufferFull":
            // Hide loader
            hideLoader()

        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/delannoyk/AudioPlayer could be helpful...

Comment: @dfi   :-  Did you found any solution for it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since **iOS 10.x**, you can make some buffer settings, for example you can decide how many seconds you'll need to buffering your video:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, tvOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, *) {
        avPlayer?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = .playWhenBufferNotEmpty
        //preferredForwardBufferDuration -> default is 0, which means `AVPlayer` handle it independently, try more seconds like 5 or 10.
        playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(5) 
    }
```

Comment: avPlayer?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = .playWhenBufferNotEmpty.   not working because its accept a bool value true or false

Comment: @DavenderVerma what iOS version give your issue?

Comment: cell.viewForVideo.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = .play.  cause an error

Comment: Try with : `player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = playerItem?.isPlaybackBufferEmpty ?? false` where `player` is your `avPlayer` and `playerItem` is your **AVPlayerItem** , good luck.

Comment: @Alessamdro. cell.viewForVideo.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = cell.viewForVideo.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackBufferEmpty ?? false
                                            cell.viewForVideo.player?.currentItem?.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(5)
                                         
                                            cell.viewForVideo.player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)

Comment: Just a 10 to 15 second video cause the video in slow

Comment: You should try to open a new question related to your issue specifying the iOS release used..